# Highmaps get country name on click when country has no data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, missing-data

I have a Highmaps-map of the world, and display data for some countries. Getting a click handler for these countries is simple. (see also [highmaps get country name on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33312551/461499))

However, I would like to be able to also detect clicks on countries without data.

I found I can add a generic click handler to the map, but the event does not give me the selected country.

Any hints?

Relevant part of the options:

```
options: {
    chart: {
        events: {
            click: function (e) { console.log( e);},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All points without data are rendered as null points by default, so you need to only enable `nullInteraction` property:

```
series: [{
  nullInteraction: true,
  point: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    },
  },
  ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wnfrza5j/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.nullInteraction

Comment: Thanks! `nullInteraction` was the magic word (that was a bit hard to guess/find)

Comment: Do we also add null select/remove in legend options ?

Comment: @user1583465, what do you exactly mean? Could you create a new question with more details and with `highcharts` tag?